# Find $lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{f_{n}(k)}{k}$ where $f_{n}(x)=\frac{sin(n(x-a))}{n(x-a)}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose that $a \in \mathbb{R}\ $and$\ \frac{\sin0}{0}=1.$

Then find $$lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{f_{n}(k)}{k}$$
where $$f_{n}(x)=\frac{\sin(n(x-a))}{n(x-a)}$$

Comment: Replace $f_n(k)/k$ by what it means, check that the series converges, and find the obvious bound.

Comment: @reuns I don't think it's so obvious.

Comment: The framework is classical cardinal sine expansions ; see https://www.jstor.org/stable/24507856

Comment: Please show you have worked on your issue.

Comment: @JeanMarie Did you spot that there is some $k^2$?

Comment: Maybe use the fact that $\frac{\sin(n(x-a))}{n(x-a)} =\frac 1 2\int_{-1}^{1}e^{in(x-a)t}dt$ to convert the sum to an integral with the power series of $log$ in it?